# How to calculate integral with n natural number

Tags: definite-integrals

Prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{2n}}{x^{2n}+{(1-x)^{2n}}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$
I have only proved that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+{(1-x)^{2}}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: replace $x$ with $x+\frac{1}{2}$ and the integral becomes $\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}\frac{1}{2}dx$.

Answer (score 5):

Making the substitution $x\to1-x$, we get
$$ \int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{x^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}\;dx=\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{2n}}{x^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}\;dx$$
and since
$$ \int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{x^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}\;dx+\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^{2n}}{x^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}\;dx=\int_0^1\;dx=1$$
it follows that 
$$ \int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{x^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}\;dx=\frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Generally Suppose we want to find

$$I(a) = \int^a_0 \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} \mathrm{d}x $$

Then since 
$$\int^a_0 \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} \mathrm{d}x = \int^a_0 \frac{f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$2I(a) = \int^a_0 \frac{f(x)+f(a-x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} \mathrm{d}x = \int^a_0 \mathrm{d}x = a$$

Hence

> $$I(a) = \int^a_0 \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} \mathrm{d}x =
>  \frac{a}{2}$$